# Can not install MysqlDB on centos Python2.7

Tags: mysql-python

I have a problem . i can`t install MysqlDB.

OS : CentOs6.8 x64
Python : 2.7.6

```
pip2.7 install mysql-python

pip install mysql-python
```

This is my Error :

> Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-rgqmTQ/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-G4kWRa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rgqmTQ/mysql-python/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this 
[dind.biz](http://dind.biz)

```
# yum install python-devel mysql-devel

# pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: YES !!!!! THIS WORKED !!!!  Did yum install mysql-devel then did pip2.7 install mysql-python and it worked !!!  Huzzah !!! And there was much rejoicing!

Comment: On Centos 8, the pip install will fail. The reason is that mysql-devel is missing an include file. You can add the file my_config.h with "sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulfitz/mysql-connector-c/master/include/my_config.h -P /usr/include/mysql/"